# What does "mir wurde ganz heiß" mean here?

Tags: idiom, idiomaticity

I ran into the text below and I wonder the following:

(1) Is the expression *mir wurde heiß und kalt* an idiom? I mean, is it a somewhat common way to express when something *gives you the chills* or sends *shivers down your spine*? Would you ever use *Schüttelfrost* to express something along these lines or is it a strictly medical term?

(2) Could *mir wurde ganz heiß* in the text be an instance of the expression *mir wurde heiß und kalt*? In any case, what does it convey?

Here is the text:

> Was mir heute passiert ist, das glaubt mir keiner:  Als ich zu Mittag
>   nichts ahnend in der Küche beim Kochen stand, läutete mein Handy. Eine
>   Frauenstimme erklärte mir, dass meine Brieftasche in der Bankfiliale
>   abgegeben worden war und ich sie dort abholen könnte. **Mir wurde ganz
>   heiß** – mir war noch gar nicht aufgefallen, dass sie fehlte. Und ich
>   hatte ja auch noch relativ viel Bargeld eingesteckt! Schnell holte ich
>   meine Handtasche hervor und suchte nach der Brieftasche. Es stimmte! 
>   Auch nach längerem Kramen in der  Tasche konnte ich sie nicht finden.
>   Mein Geld war tatsächlich verschwunden!

Comment: Cold heat, kalter Schweiß, die nakte Angst, sheer dread,...

Comment: Wie kommst Du auf kalt? Es gibt keinen Hinweis darauf.Dass jmd. heiß wird, ist eine anatomische Beschreibung. Dass jmd. heiß und kalt wird auch, aber eine andere.

Answer (score 1):

(2)

yes, in the text you could also say "heiß und kalt" instead of just "heiß"

(1)

[shivers down your spine] is a good translation. It is not really a medical term, but yes it could mean youre getting well temperatured, but usually "ganz" in this context indicates some emotional aspect, where no temperature is meant, but the situation.

Answer (score 0):

"mir ist kalt" means "I am/feel cold".

"mir wurde kalt" means "I became cold / "I was starting to feel cold."

"Ganz" in this case just means "very".

<strike>It is not a strictly medical term.</strike>

edit:
It seems I misunderstood one part in your first question. Schüttelfrost is a strictly medical term. Do detach it it from the medical connotation you can say "Es fühlte sich (fast) wie Schüttelfrost an.", meaning "It (almost) felt like chills and fevers.

If you replace "kalt" with "heiß" (hot) you'll find the appropriate meanings above, too. 
In this specific case, "Mir wurde ganz heiß" is meant literally. It refers to the adrenaline rush that you can, e.g. when you get scared. This is the case when the narrator suddenly realises that she lost her purse.

Comment: Die Frage ist aber nach "heiß"

Comment: Frage eins ging auch um kalt. Die Bedeutung ändert sich nicht, wenn man kalt durch heiß ersetzt (entsprechend). Habe jetzt aber nochmal mehr Bezug drauf genommen

Answer (score 0):

(1) Yes, it is exactly what you think it is. In German, you can also say „mir lief es [heiß und] kalt über den Rücken“ oder „ein Schauer lief mir über den Rücken“, but you can also say „mir wurde heiß und kalt“.

(2) I would say so. For me, it sounds a little bit more uncommon to say „mir wurde (ganz) heiß“. The other samples are used more often.

Answer (score 0):

"Mir wurde ganz heiß" ist eine anatomische Beobachtung, unabhängig von der Sprache, in der sie ausgedrückt wird. Dass jemandem abwechselnd heiß und kalt wird, kommt auch vor, aber ist eben etwas anderes.

Anzunehmen, der Autor habe zum falschen Sprachmittel gegriffen, ist so sinnvoll wie anzunehmen, dass es abends im Wohnzimmer war, nicht mittags in der Küche.